# Python NameError: name 'include' is not defined

Tags: python, django, nameerror

I'm currently developing a website with the framework Django (I'm very beginner), but I have a problem with Python: since I have created my templates, I can't run server anymore for this reason (the stack trace points to a line in file *urls.py*):

```
<stacktrace>
...
path('apppath/', include('myapp.urls')),
NameError: name 'include' is not defined
```

Where can I import `include` from?

Comment: attach your code and full error stack plz.

Comment: Moderators, just want to point out here that this type of question is SUPER useful because it's short and has an answer.  You're suggesting posting a bunch of code and etc., and the result is that nobody answers those. (ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46158714/include-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 287, accepted):

Guessing on the basis of whatever little information provided in the question, I think you might have forgotten to add the following import in your `urls.py` file.

```
from django.conf.urls import include
```

Comment: Thank you, it was that ! But i have now an other issue : django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<module 'project.urls' from '/Users/anatole/Desktop/Web/project/urls.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

Comment: Please post your  `urls.py` file.

Comment: It found the solution, i wrote urlspatterns instead of urlpatterns ! Now my problem is that i have an 404 page not found ; this is my urls.py :

Comment: from django.conf.urls import url, patterns
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^date$', views.date_actuelle),
]

Comment: What url you are trying on the browser?

Comment: local host : http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Comment: this is my main urls.py : from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from vitrine import views, urls

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^vitrine/', include('vitrine.urls')),
]

Comment: There is no url defined for `''` (root url),  so you are getting 404. Try 127.0.0.1:8000/vitrine/date.

Comment: Thanks, this helped! It looks like from "django.conf.urls import include, url" from Django tutorial does not look very different from the default "django.conf.urls import url" in the project file.

Comment: thanks... in my case I just add `include` in django import `from django.urls import path,include`

Comment: thank you. for me django 3.1, there already exists: from django.urls import path
so, i only add include after path
become like this: from django.urls import path, include