# Include is not defined

Tags: python, django

To clarify Security is the project folder, and Accounts is the app.  I'm sure this is an elementary issue that i'm overlooking, but i've been struggling to get my manged.py commands to work because the following error:

NameError: name 'include' is not defined.

My project (Security) urls.py is the following, which does have include:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^account/', include('accounts.url')),
]
```

My Accounts apps.py contains:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


    class AccountsConfig(AppConfig):
        name = 'accounts'
```

My Accounts app urls.py is the following:

```
      from django.conf.urls import url, include

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

My settings.py has accounts in the installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'accounts',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

After adding include to be in both urls.py for my project and app, i'm now greeted with the following stating accounts module is not found.

```
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 948, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'accounts.url'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using the `include` function in a file in which you're not importing it. You should add

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
```

to your security app urls.py

**EDIT**

For the second error, try and change the way you include the urls from accounts. Replace `accounts.url` for it's relative path, starting with the apps folder. For example

```
url(r'^account/', include('accounts.urls')),
```

If you have doubts, add your folder structure to the question and I will update the answer properly.

Comment: Doesn't having the following in my project folder use include, in my sec app?  To clarify Security is the name of the project and Accounts is the name of the app...   from django.conf.urls import url, include

from . import views

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't work that way. You have to import `include` in the file you want to use it.

Comment: Please, try it and tell me if there's another error.

Comment: I updated the code, the include error went away, but now it gives accounts.url modulenotfounderror.  I also, updated the code above and error.

Comment: Reading what you added, I changed the answer, and I think the only problem you had was the last letter 's' missing from 'accounts.urls'

Comment: That was exactly the issue i was missing the s.  Appreciate the help Francisco.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution:

```
from django.conf.urls import include
```

import it on `urls.py` page of your project.

Answer (score 0):

```
In your rootapp.py you have used
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^account/', include('accounts.url')),
]
Here you have used include('accounts.url')
But you have not imported include 
So your code should be

from django.apps import AppConfig


class AccountsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'accounts'

my security app urls.py is the following:

from django.conf.urls import url , include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^account/', include('accounts.url')),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi i'm not sure but it works for me. I just installed the module include with this command (in the virtual environment):

`pip install include`

The script no longer displays error.

Answer (score 0):

First try 'pip install include'

or

you forgot to save your views.py and urls.py

or

add this in your urls.py  'from django.conf.urls import include'